# How to set the slidesPerView with partial slides on both ends using SwiperJS?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

Im new to SwiperJS. Right now my code is displaying 3 visible items with partial items on both sides. However I want 4 visible items on it instead of 3.

[image]

I don't know if theres something that I missed on `swiper-api` like `slidesPerView`, `slidesPerGroup` or anything else.

Check my code below:

```js
var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiperNav", {
  spaceBetween: 16,
  slidesPerView: 4.5,
  slidesPerGroup: 1,
  centeredSlides: true,
  loop: true,
  /*loopAdditionalSlides: 6,*/
  freeMode: true,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
  allowTouchMove: true,
  keyboard: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
});
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiperFor", {
  spaceBetween: 16,
  effect: "fade",
  thumbs: {
    swiper: swiper2,
  },
});
```

```css
.container, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm, .container-xl, .container-xxl {
  max-width: 1320px !important;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.mySwiperFor {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mySwiperNav {
  height: 20%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.mySwiperNav .swiper-slide {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
}

.mySwiperNav .swiper-wrapper {
  & .swiper-slide-visible:not(.swiper-slide-fully-visible) {
    opacity: .3;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-12">
  <div class="swiper mySwiperFor">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="--swiper-navigation-color: #000; --swiper-pagination-color: #000" class="swiper mySwiperNav">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```